# How to display values from array vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, binding, key, array-key

```
<div id="app"> 
    <div v-for="(value, index) in additionalOptions">
        <input type="text" v-model="additionalOptions[0]" />
    </div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        additionalOptions: [{
            "side_dish": ["Potato", "Apple"]
        }]
    },
});
```

response is [object Object]

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am tottaly stuck with this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use objects instead of arrays.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      additionalOptions: [{
        side_dish: {
          0: "Potato",
          1: "Apple"
        }
      }]
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="option in additionalOptions" :key="option">
        <div v-for="(side, side_index) in option.side_dish" :key="side_index">
          <input type="text" v-model="option.side_dish[side_index]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
     {{additionalOptions}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to show an input field by `side_dish`:

- `additionalOptions` is an array with only one element so you must select [0] and then get the `side_dish` property
- iterate on `side_dish` with v-for

Code:

```
<div id="app"> 
    <div v-for="value in additionalOptions[0].side_dish">
        <input type="text" v-model="value" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfxej41y/2/)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you mean